# Scala. Convert Array[Byte] to java.io.File

Tags: scala, file, type-conversion

I have an `Array[Byte]`, which was initially in `pdf` format. I need to convert it to `java.io.File`. 
**Update:** I have an email-service, which can send emails with attachments (files). Files must be in `java.io.File` format. But files in the request to my service come as `Array[Byte]` with `base64` encoding. I can't afford file creation every time, because it will clog my memory.

Comment: Do you want to write it to a file system?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc no, I need to take it to `val` without creating a new file

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Please tell us what you actually want to solve. Bring more context to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.io.File` is not a storage of the file content but only an address of the file on storage - if the API doesn't let you pass content in another way, you have to use temporary files, no other option.

At best, you can make sure that they are deleted after usage:

- create them in `/tmp` using `File.createTempFile`
- mark them as `deleteOnExit` if current procedure fails and/or
- call `delete` on `file` in `finally` block

If you are using Cats Effect it would make sense to do something like:

```
val withTempFile = Resource.make[F, File] {
  F.delay(File.createTempFile)
} { file =>
  F.delay(file.delete)
}

withTempFile.use { file =>
  // operation in F
}
```

If you are using plain Scala, loan pattern can work out:

```
def withTempFile(thunk: File => A): A = {
  val tmpFile = File.createTempFile
  try {
    thunk(tmpFile)
  } finally {
    tmpFile.delete
  }
}

withTempFile { file =>
  // operation
}
```

Once you have temporary file that is (almost) certain to be deleted you can write to it and pass the file reference to your service.

If you want to avoid using a tmp file on disk you can consider something like RAM disk if you have the possibility. The bottom line is - if API doesn't let you use `Array[Byte]` and only accepts `File` you **have to** write this file on disk. Or look for a different service provider/API.